# How to optimize this UNION SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ( 
                        SELECT  FundId AS Id,
                                PeriodYearMonth
                        FROM [Fund.Period] F
                        INNER JOIN (
                                    SELECT * FROM (
                                                    SELECT  FundId as Id, 
                                                    MIN(PeriodYearMonth) AS MinPeriodYearMonth
                                                    FROM (
                                                        SELECT  FundId,
                                                                PeriodYearMonth,
                                                                PublishedOn
                                                        FROM    [Fund.Period] FP
                                                        UNION ALL --Changed to UNION ALL as it is more efficient and we wont ever need a UNION as the result set would never match
                                                        SELECT  FundId,
                                                                MAX(PeriodYearMonth) + 1,
                                                                NULL
                                                        FROM      [Fund.Period]
                                                        GROUP BY FundId
                                                        ) FP WHERE PublishedOn IS NULL GROUP BY FundId
                                                    ) MFP
                                    )  FP ON F.FundId = FP.Id AND (F.PeriodYearMonth = FP.MinPeriodYearMonth OR (f.PeriodYearMonth +1) = FP.MinPeriodYearMonth) 
                           ) FP
```

If possible, I would like to remove the UNION ALL. Does anyone know how this can be optimized?

Comment: I don't get why you need the `UNION ALL` - You're selecting the `Min(PeriodYearMonth)` yet your second statement in the UNION is pulling in `MAX(PeriodYearMonth)+1` - Seems to me all your results will come from the first portion of that query. Am I missing something? - Overall, it looks like you could write that whole query better by moving the `WHERE` clause within the sub-query, etc....

Comment: is there any record with NULL value in PublishedOn column?

Comment: @JaydipRakholiya Yes there are

Comment: @JohnBustos This is not the case, basically the query selects the MIN(PeriodYearMonth) for unpublished funds(i.e where PublishedOn IS NULL) but if it has been published then it will select the MAX(PeriodYearMonth) + 1

Answer (score 0):

removed union all

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ( 
                    SELECT  FundId AS Id,
                            PeriodYearMonth
                    FROM [Fund.Period] F
                    INNER JOIN (
                                SELECT * FROM (
                                                SELECT  FundId as Id, 
                                                MIN(PeriodYearMonth) AS MinPeriodYearMonth,MAX(PeriodYearMonth) + 1 as PeriodYearMonth
                                                FROM (
                                                    SELECT  FundId,
                                                            PeriodYearMonth,
                                                            PublishedOn
                                                    FROM    [Fund.Period] FP

                                                    ) FP WHERE PublishedOn IS NULL 
                                                    GROUP BY FundId
                                                ) MFP
                                )  FP ON F.FundId = FP.Id AND (F.PeriodYearMonth = FP.MinPeriodYearMonth OR (f.PeriodYearMonth +1) = FP.MinPeriodYearMonth) 
                       ) FP
```

Comment: Hi, this wont work as PeriodYearMonth is not in the GROUP BY Statement

Comment: @Andrew answer eidted

Comment: i used max(PeriodYearMonth ) so no need in group by clause PeriodYearMonth